# What does the first argument of ReactDOM.render take?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am recently learning React on my own, but I find a confusing usage of `ReactDOM.render`

```js
function UniversityList(){
    return React.createElement(
        "ul",
        {id: "universities"}, 
        React.createElement("li", 
                            {id: "Waterloo", 
                             className: "University"}, 
                            "University of Waterloo"),
        React.createElement("li",
                            {id: "Laurier",
                             className: "University"},
                            "Laurier University"
                           ));
};

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(UniversityList, null, null),
                document.getElementById("root"));
```

In the code above, why do  we pass the `UniversityList`, the function string as the first parameter to `React.createElement(UniversityList, null, null)`.

1. Don't we always pass the type of the html tag we want as the first parameter? (I just started to learn components, but I still do not get the idea)
2. There was no where the function `UniversityList` was invoked in the code above. How can the React element with type `"ul"` get returned by `UniversityList`?
3. The function `UniversityList` was not invoked, but how did the `ReactDOM.render` successfully rendered the page? The `React.createElement(UniversityList, null, null)` returned a React object like:

```js
{
    $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
    key: null
    props: { children: null }
    __proto__: Object
    ref: null
    type: UniversityList()
    _owner: null
    _store: {validated: false}
}
```

Where are the list items I want to rendered in this React object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good read of the react docs would help your understanding quite a bit.

[React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

> ```
> React.createElement(
>   type,
>   [props],
>   [...children]
> )
> ```
>
> Create and return a new [`React element`](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) of the given type. The type
> argument can be either a tag name string (such as `'div'` or `'span'`), a
> [`React component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) type (a class or a function), or a [`React fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactfragment)
> type.

### Question 1

> Don't we always pass the type of the html tag we want as the first
> parameter? (I just started to learn components, but I still do not get
> the idea)

You can specify html elements or other react components.

### Question 2

> There was no where the function `UniversityList` was invoked in the code
> above. How can the React element with type `"ul"` get returned by
> `UniversityList`?

This is typical in react, you don't invoke the functions directly, but instead are passing them off to the React framework to render and handle all the component lifecycle functions, like mounting, updating, and unmounting.

For example, a functional component may be written as such:

```
const MyComponent = ({ count }) => <div>{count}</div>;
```

But you won't ever actually invoke the function like `MyComponent({ count: 3 })`, but rather write it in JSX as `<MyComponent count={3} />`.

The second text block explains this a bit:

> Code written with [`JSX`](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) will be converted to use `React.createElement()`.
> You will not typically invoke `React.createElement()` directly if you
> are using JSX. See [`React Without JSX`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) to learn more.

### Question 3

> The function UniversityList was not invoked, but how did the
> ReactDOM.render successfully rendered the page?

Same reason as for question 2, the component is passed to the React framework to handle the rendering and lifecycle of it. `React.createElement(UniversityList, null, null)` creates a new element/component, `UniversityList`, to render into the DOM, and passes no `props` nor `children`. If you look at the `UniversityList` function definition it passes `{id: "universities"}` as a prop and creates two `li` elements as children.

Comment: Much appreciation! I am currently reading the kindle version of "Learning React"  published by O'Reilly. I like to write my own explanations of examples and concepts presented in the book. However, I found something I cannot explain during the process. Thanks for your detailed explanation and patience. Once again, thank you!